# Git submodule update after pull a brach

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm trying to make update on submodules by that:

```
git submodule update --recursive
```

And the .gitmodules is:

```
[submodule "test"]
    path = test
    url = https://testuser@gitlab.org/test/test.git
```

Another developer has updated `.gitmodules` on `develop` branch like that:

```
[submodule "test"]
    path = test
    url = git@gitlab.org/test/test.git
```

I've followed these codes:

```
git pull origin develop
git checkout develop
git submodule update --recursive
```

I've checked the `.gitmodules` file, it has changed, but it stil ask me the testuser's password. I couldn't understand what have done wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git submodule update` doesn't use `.gitmodules` directly — it uses URLs from `.git/config` copied there by `git submodule init`. When you need to update the URLs from changed `.gitmodules` run [`git submodule sync`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-sync--recursive--ltpathgt82308203).